# jQuery selectors with more than 1 criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, css

trying to do something pretty obvious really but its kinda not making any sense / not working for me ...

The idea is simple, when the document is loaded $(document).ready() get all input elements that have attribute type="text" on them and add the css class "textbox" ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var textboxes = $(":input [type = 'text']");
        textboxes.each().addClass("textbox");
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work ?? ...

EDIT:

Wow .. still have a lot to learn about jquery-isms ... starting to love jquery though :) it's simplicity really does the trick.

Comment: You dont have to iterate through the elements. If you execute methods on the selector, they will be (most of the time) be applied to all elements matched by the selector.

Comment: dam u guys are fast !!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='text']").addClass("textbox");
});
```

No need for the colon before the element `input`.

`$("input[type='text']")` will reference all elements so no need for an `each()`

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue in your code is that you have a space between the `:input` pseudo-selector and the `type` attr selector.  Removing the space works.

That said, `.each()` is meant to receive a function which should run on each element in the matched collection. It then returns the collection for further chaining. In your example, the given each was useless so I removed it. Further adjustments to make the swlector match properly but efficiently should give you want you want:

```
$( function()
{
    $( 'input[type="text"]' ).addClass( 'textbox' );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't this work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type = 'text']").addClass("textbox");
    });
</script>
```

Is there some reason you are first evaluating to a var?

Comment: @Boswirth99: sure: as already mentioned there is no need for an `each()` :)

Comment: yeh right ... why the downvote .. that was pretty valid thing to ask ... and to answer that ... no reason other than me trying to figure out what i was selecting :) u got my +1 to rebalance :)

Comment: I did not give the down vote, but I will explain the problem with your answer.  No, that code will not work as there is a space in the selector. Testing code before offering it as an answer (in the form of a question, no less) would help you avoid down votes.

Comment: @Bosworth99: not anymore no. However code still isn't valid :D

Comment: The space between `input` and `[` is significant. This would look for any element with a `type` attribute equal to `text` within an `input` element.

Comment: @JAAulde - asking questions shouldn't be downvoted. Perhaps there was some other unknown reasons for, in this case, first capturing as a var. I know its not necessary, you know its not necessary, but questions aren't always completely verbose, and figuring that out I think completely warranted.

Comment: I recognize that the space between the input is important. I didn't check it to ensure it worked, as I indeed should of, but its just a simple statement. My bad - but still not worth a downvote. (and thanks for fixing that @wardy)  - -

Comment: IMO, questions should be in comments, not posted as answers. But like I said, I'm not the one that down-voted. Further, I did not mention anything about storing it in a var--I have no issue with that and never mentioned it.

Comment: @Bosworth99: I downvoted since your answer isn't working. So live with the downvote. Why would I not downvote an invalid answer? http://jsfiddle.net/ssFf8/

Comment: @JAAulde - I know you didn't DV it - and you may certainly be right about starting an answer with a question. I was just interested why the OP was first storing the results, and confused about how he was going about it...

Comment: @Bosworth99: There was NO downvote because some question in the answer! You're answer just is WRONG!

Comment: @PeeHaa - LOL i dont know - i spose that's exactly why you would downvote. I don't have to like it tho!! (Drivebys do kinda suck tho.)

Comment: @Bosworth99: last thing I'm going to say about this. Otherwise this will turn in a discussion (isn't it already :P). Everyone hates drivebys and you don't have to like the fact getting downvoted :). However the downvote system is in place to make sure good / the best answers get the most attention of both OP and other users viewing a thread. It's part of the game. Yuo don't want to know howmany downvotes i got until now :D Either by myself being stupid / some random unexplained downvotes. :D

Comment: @PeeHaa - props for the +1 answer. Cheers dude.